# How to get a distant computer's configuration using ssh and terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal, configuration, hardware

I need to get the hardware specifications on a distant computer to which I have access through ssh. How can I get this distant computer's hardware (and software) configuration using ssh and terminal?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distant machine is on linux ?

**If yes** :

connect though ssh via : `ssh user@ip`

And type one of theses commands in terminal (depending of distributions) :

http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-hardware-info/

Bye :)

Comment: Would you know for Mac ?

Comment: Mac got a unix core so it may work.

But you can always try this : http://www.itechlounge.net/2013/09/mac-osx-get-full-system-information-through-terminal/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help